# how to find x power n using for loop till user don't want to exit

Tags: c

I have done upto this and i don't know how to proceed further

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x,n,m,i;

printf("Enter the value of x: ");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("\nEnter the value of n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
m=m*x;
printf("x=%d;n=%d;m=%d",x,n,m);
while(m!=-1);
m=m*x;
i=i+1;
printf("enter the -1 to end");
scanf("%d",&m);
}
```

Will you please help me to write a sample program to show x power n till user don't want to exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

Just need a little clean-up.

Set `m=1`
Choose a different variable to ask for -1.
Move the `printf()` to the while loop.
Format

```
int main() {
  int x, n, m, i;

  printf("Enter the value of x: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("\nEnter the value of n: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  m = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    m = m * x;
  while (n != -1) {
    printf("x=%d;n=%d;m=%d\n", x, n, m);
    m = m * x;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("enter the -1 to end ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  }
}
```

---

Looks like OP went away ....